# postgres could not accept SSL connection: EOF detected

Tags: python, postgresql, ssl

I am trying to set up ssl (self-signed certs) for a postgres DB (version 9.6) I have attached to my python flask gunicorn app. I have been running the postgres server without ssl just fine, but am trying to increase security on the application.

I've used the following tutorials:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/libpq-ssl.html
- https://blog.jelastic.com/2016/08/31/establish-secure-ssl-connection-to-postgresql-db-server/
- https://www.howtoforge.com/postgresql-ssl-certificates

and while they were very useful, I can't seem to get passed this issue (in my log file):

```
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-11-07 13:15:47 EST
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started

LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: EOF detected // THIS LINE HERE
```

The application runs, but not over ssl.

Here is my `postgres.conf` (what I thought was relevant):

```
listen_addresses = '*'                                                 
port = 7654                            
ssl = on                              
ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL'                                        
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on          
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'          
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'            
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'             
ssl_ca_file = 'root.crt'
```

and here is my `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
hostssl all         all    0.0.0.0/0             trust clientcert=1
# I've also tried:
#hostssl all         myUser    0.0.0.0/0             md5 clientcert=1
#hostssl all         all    0.0.0.0/0             md5
```

Here is some [trace](https://gist.github.com/jdell64/66246b80849411e8f4ba4edc2762942d) logging.

Which indicates an issue with [be-secure-openssl.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/libpq/be-secure-openssl.c), on this line:

```
if (!SSL_context)
    {
        ereport(COMMERROR,
                (errcode(ERRCODE_PROTOCOL_VIOLATION), // THIS LINE
                 errmsg("could not initialize SSL connection: SSL context not set up")));
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error on the client side? Can you see anything unusual in a network trace?

Comment: At this point, I don't think I've gotten that far? I get that error when starting the server. I have tried client side just to see if I can still connect, and I can, just not over ssl.

Comment: Oh... okay, so here is where I was confused... I think that error is generated by my app connecting to it, not by starting up the server... I had a startup script that both started the pg server and my app at the same time. Separating those commands, I think that is what caused it?

Comment: Yes, the problem is not server startup, but a client trying to connect. What happens is that the client unexpectedly closes the TCP connection (EOF reading from the socket). This error is thrown when the connection is closed by the peer while PostgreSQL waits in [`SSL_accept()`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SSL_accept(3)). Basically, the server waits for the client to start an SSL session (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-flow.html#idm46046840017008)). To solve the problem, find out why the client closes the connection.

Comment: I will defer to your answer (if I can give you enough info to post one); and delete my answer. I solved it by deleting my client certs (they had the wrong permissions on them, and since I regenerated my certs 8123847124 times, they were wrong), I turrned off all the host entries in my conf file in favor of hostssl ones.

Comment: I can't really give a correct answer, since I don't know what exactly caused your client to terminate the connection. But good to know that you solved the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158524/discussion-between-jeff-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: I now have a similar issue with a AWS RDS Postgre 10.4 R1 database  `2018-11-27 10:42:51 UTC:10.0.23.x(53752):[unknown]@[unknown]:[31951]:LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: EOF detected`